# Deploying a spring-mvc application failed

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working with `spring-mvc` with hibernate, and I have deployed my application on go daddy server, when I open any `html` file it works well, But on opening a `jsp` file, gives me a 404 file not found error. Please any one can help me with the problem...?
I m using Spring 3.0,
Jdk 1.7.0_04,
apache-tomcat 6.0.32

The `web.xml` I'm using is
**web.xml :**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
            <display-name>seekersworkroom</display-name>
            <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>/view/Index.jsp</welcome-file>
            </welcome-file-list>
             <servlet>
            <servlet-name>imageupload</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.seekersworkroom.controller.imageuploadController</servlet-class> 
          </servlet>



        <servlet-mapping>
             <servlet-name>imageupload</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/imageupload.htm</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>


          <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Userimageupload</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.seekersworkroom.controller.UserimageuploadController</servlet-class>

          </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
             <servlet-name>Userimageupload</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/Userimageupload.htm</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>seekersworkroom</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

          </servlet>

          <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>seekersworkroom</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>


          <servlet>
                <servlet-name>seekersworkroom-servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>


            <listener>
                <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
            </listener>

            <context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>
                    /WEB-INF/seekersworkroom-servlet.xml,
                    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml

                </param-value>
            </context-param>

            <!-- Spring Security -->
            <filter>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
            </filter>

            <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
            </filter-mapping>


        </web-app>


      The welcome doesnot dispaly index.jsp file but if the same is replaced by index.html it shows this file. And by opening any url eith .jsp extension it shows 404 error.


    seekersworkroom-servlet:



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


        <bean name="/login/*.htm" id="AdminprofileController" class="com.seekersworkroom.controller.AdminprofileController">

        </bean>



       <bean name="/Index/*.htm" id="IndexController" class="com.seekersworkroom.controller.IndexController">
        <property name="indexDAO" ref="IndexDAO" />
         <property name="skillsaddedDAO" ref="SkillsaddedDAO" />
             <property name="skillsDAO" ref="SkillsDAO"></property>
         <property name="userDAO" ref="UserDAO" />
             <property name="acountryDAO" ref="acountryDAO" />
          <property name="bregDAO" ref="BregistrationDAO" />
          <property name="cregistrationDAO" ref="CregistrationDAO" />
         <property name="ccontactDAO" ref="CcontactDAO" />
         <property name="caddressDAO" ref="CaddressDAO" />
          <property name="asubcategoryDAO" ref="AsubcategoryDAO" />
          <property name="cportfolioDAO" ref="CportfolioDAO" />
            <property name="keywordDAO" ref="KeywordDAO" />
                 <property name="bcreatejobDAO" ref="BcreatejobDAO" />
         <property name="messageDAO" ref="messageDAO"></property>
         <property name="userimageDAO" ref="UserimageDAO" />
        </bean>



        <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/view/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

        <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" >
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/skw"/>
            <property name="username" value="root"/>
            <property name="password" value="root"/>
        </bean>


        <bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">  
          <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />  
          <property name="mappingResources">  
           <list>  


            <value>com/seekersworkroom/VO/User.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/seekersworkroom/VO/buyerregistration.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/seekersworkroom/VO/contractorregistration.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/seekersworkroom/VO/Contractorcontact.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/seekersworkroom/VO/Contractoraddress.hbm.xml</value>  
            <value>com/seekersworkroom/VO/Contractorkeyword.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/seekersworkroom/VO/Userimage.hbm.xml</value>



           </list>  
          </property>  

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                </props>
        </property>    
         </bean>




    <bean id="acountryDAO" class="com.seekersworkroom.DAO.AcountryDAO" >
            <property name="sessionFactory"><ref bean="sessionFactory"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="AcategoriesDAO" class="com.seekersworkroom.DAO.AcategoriesDAO" >
            <property name="sessionFactory"><ref bean="sessionFactory"/></property>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

This is the servlet file in which the annotaions are used to cal to particular controllers.
This servlet contains the beans through which the request is redirected to particular controllers.
But the main problem is `jsp` file is not working only...
What can I do in `web.xml` so that it allows me to access the jsp file on server side??
Is that the problem with Spring framework or  the web.xml file is missing something???

Comment: what does your tomcat logs say?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Can you send us the class that has the servlet annotation that's giving you the 404?

Comment: Actually the application works fine in local server, but on deploying it shows 404 error for jsp files.

Comment: When you say you are using JDK and apache tomcat, you are using them on your local or on godaddy too. Reason, I am asking that because once previously someone was trying to run java app on a server and later figured out they don't have java supported by hosting service provider.

Comment: I am using JDK and apache tomcat on both local as well as on godaddy

Answer (score 0):

I assume the jsp you are accessing is outside of your WEB-INF folder. In such cases, use `<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/" />` in your seekersworkroom-servlet.xml; and access the jsp using url `http://yourdomain/static/yourjspname.jsp`.

Also, you may not need to protect your static resources; So, use
`<http pattern="/static/**" security="none" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"/>` in your spring security configuration file

Comment: I tried using <mvc:resource> but still the error remains as "The requested document was not found on this server."